# Getting error while binding checkbox in Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-grid

Getting below error while binding Kendo MVC Grid for select box.

**(44): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Select' takes 0 arguments**

Below is the my code:

```
@{Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                      .Name("EmpGrid")
                      .Pageable()
                      .Filterable()
                      .DataSource(d => d
                          .Server()
                          .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.empId))
                          .PageSize(25)
                      )
                      .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                         columns.Select();
                         columns.Bound(r => r.Name).Width(160);
                      }).Render();
                }
```

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong.

If I removes "columns.Select();" from columns it's working.

Thanks.

Comment: "No overload for method 'Select' takes 0 arguments" means that you can not use it with NO parameters. Have a look here on some examples: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid

Comment: Thanks for response, I implemented my code from here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/checkbox-selection

Comment: Have you tried adding the .Width(50) to it? I don't and have never used Telerik so i can't help you more than that but I am sure that there are enough people who will.

Comment: Yes, added the width property but width is for table column space. Thanks.

Comment: which version of the framework are you using?

Comment: Version: 2017.2.621

Comment: Using template option to get check box in the grid :  columns.Template(@<text><input type="checkbox"/></text>).HeaderTemplate(@<text><input type="checkbox" /></text>);

Answer (score 1):

I think due to Kendo old version it's not binding. Accomplished it by using template option like below.

```
columns.Template(@<text><input type="checkbox"/></text>).HeaderTemplate(@<text><input type="checkbox" /></text>); columns.Template(@<text><input type="checkbox"/></text>).HeaderTemplate(@<text><input type="checkbox" /></text>);
```

Thanks